Can I customize pages with mere PHP instead of Twig?
I want to add a year counter at the end of any Drupal page on my website. I could achieve it with the following code to the page.html.twig file in a sub-theme.
<span>{{ 'now' | date('Y') }}</span>

I don't want to edit any template file in my sub-theme. Instead, I would like to simply add some PHP code, for example the following one.
<span><?php echo date("Y"); ?></span>

Can I customize pages using just PHP instead of using Twig in a template file?

You can for example place a custom block plugin on the page containing PHP code, but if you are looking for this simple template solution the second D7 code line translates to the first code line for D8+.

As 4uk4 says, Drupal 8+ went all-in on Twig.  So you can use PHP but you will have to write a lot of boilerplate code, or you can learn Twig.  Since the entire theme system is based on Twig now, it seems a very unusual requirement to say "I don't want to edit Twig files in my sub-theme"; that's the mechanism provided for this kind of thing.

Also it's worth noting that one of the reasons Drupal 8+ switched to Twig is to prevent bad PHP in theme code from creating security vulnerabilities. Twig is more limited than PHP, but those limitations are there for protection.

Simple answer: You can (with modules like Twig PHP filter), but don't do it. Aside from the severe security problems, code like this will not work correctly due caching. If you absolutely need PHP in your templates, then Drupal might not be the tool fitting your requirements.

That’s bad practice, use twig.

You could provide a custom block from a custom module

I appreciate all the constructive criticism in the comments. As I am not a themer or anything near it I avoid "messing around" with the Twig files and just want to clone some regions and add some simple PHP or Twig to the end of pages of the site. I work with Drupal nearly 14 years and just love it and don't recognize myself ever stop. As a non themer I just don't want to copy-paste Twig files and directories to my sub theme and access them by strict hierarchy and changing large structures of Twig directives (most of which I don't understand) just for a simple task as cloning a region.

and more so I don't want to maintain such sub theme Twig files in case the core general theme such as Olivero is updated (rare, but can always happen) and there are conflicts.

Until Drupal core will be more friendly to non themers, making it much simpler to clone existing regions to better organize blocks or add some HTML-PHP (vanilla or Twig) to the end of pages of the site, then you might want to add an answer summing all this discussion with a clear cut conclusion that will be a guidance for people like myself who love Drupal but are not themers.

I am not a themer too, but Twig template files do not make more difficult for me to change a template file. Quite the opposite, it's easier to forget a character in a PHPTemplate file which causes some parsing error. If you do want to avoid to touch template files as much as possible, you can still use some theming hooks. That is not different from Drupal 7, where a template file should just contain the minimal code necessary to output the HTML markup, and not code to update the user password, for example.

Honestly, with the energy you've already spent posting questions and considering/responding to comments, you could have done a couple of basic Twig tutorials, and it would never be a problem again :) Learning the minimum to do a thing doesn't mean you have to become a thing-er, it just makes you a more valuable resource

14 years of Drupal and you haven't learned a bit of theming?Anyhow, you're trying to do this the hard way. Plus if another person is going to maintain the site in the future you should do them a favor by doing it the proper way.

@NoSssweat This seems more the case of a person who wants to avoid editing Twig files. You are right that doing it the right way will help any person that needs to maintain the theme/site.

The right way for a theme developer to fully customize a page is to create a template file and optionally implement hook_preprocess_HOOK() for that template file.
Other hooks that can modify how a page is rendered are either limited in scope or specific for modules (which means themes cannot implement them).
For example, hook_page_attachments_alter() can be implemented by themes, but its purpose is just adding attachments (for example, assets) to a page before it is rendered. hook_page_top() adds a renderable array to the top of the page, but it is invoked when a module implements it.
With hooks, you would be writing PHP code, but with only hooks implemented by a theme you would not get a fully customization as with template files.
